# compare two group data in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem to compare two tables:
A

```
id x
1  2
1  5
1  4
1  6
```

B

```
id x
1  2
1  5
1  4
1  6
```

I want to know if the data in table A and B are same with id=1.

Answer (score 1):

This will list any rows with `id=1` that are in `a` but aren't in `b`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id AND a.x = b.x AND a.id = 1
WHERE b.x IS NULL;
```

In the left join, `b.x` will be null when there's an {a.id, a.x} pair that doesn't have a corresponding {b.id, b.x} pair.

To list any rows with `id=1` that are in `b` but not in `a`, just turn the query around:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON b.id = a.id AND b.x = z.x AND b.id = 1
WHERE z.x IS NULL;
```

Combine the two to find which rows are in `a` but not `b` and are in `b` but not `a`. If the query returns no rows then the values in both tables for `id=1` are identical. If it does return rows, they're the ones that are different.

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.id AND a.x = b.x AND a.id = 1
WHERE b.x IS NULL
UNION SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM b
LEFT JOIN a ON b.id = a.id AND b.x = z.x AND b.id = 1
WHERE z.x IS NULL;
```